# How to show a general graphic (not a Plot) inside a Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm building a little interface, which consists only of a button, as you can see here:

```
Button["File Input",
   file = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]]; 
            Print[principalFunction[file]]]
```

Now I'd like to insert the produced graphic and the button inside a `Manipulate`. Note that I'm not using Plot, Plot3D, etc. -- the graphics are produced by `principalFunction` as the final result of evaluating many other functions.

Comment: Instead of an image give us the code? Adapt it so we don't need the file? :) Or you can just provide the file as well.

Comment: ok, I've done what you asked

Comment: Try `Module[{file = {0, 0}}, Panel[Column@{Button["File Input", file = ToExpression@Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"], "Data"];], Dynamic@ListLinePlot@file}]]`. The important  parts here are `Module`, `Panel` (for the `Manipulate-lookalike`) and `Dynamic` for the update :) Works with a text file containing `{{1,0},{1,1}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a fancy answer but questions need to be answered and I hope this answers the (quite unclear) question.

As mentioned in the comments the important parts in the following codes are `Module`, `Panel` for the *Manipulate lookalike* and `Dynamic` for the update. Since you mentioned that you were not using `Plot` here is an example with a `Graphic` entity.

```
Module[{file = {{0, 0}}, r = 1},
  Panel[Column@{
    Button["File Input",file = ToExpression@
      Import["http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=eaey3Ehk"]; r = .5;],
    Dynamic@Graphics[Disk[#, r] & /@ file]}]]
```

[image]

In your case you would have `principalFunction@file` instead of `Graphics[Disk[#, r] & /@ file]` and `file = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];` with the operations (such as `ToExpression` in my case) you need to in order to use your data after using `Import`.

Version with `Manipulate` (thus no `Dynamic` nor `Panel`):

```
Module[{file = {{0, 0}}, r = 1},
  Manipulate[Graphics[Disk[#, r] & /@ file, ImageSize -> {200, 200}], 
    Button["File Input", file = 
      ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=eaey3Ehk"];  
      r = .5;]]]
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank to you I've been able to help a mate...It's not clear to me the second example you wrote, the one with Manipulate but the first was successful!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)